# RSA encoding function is bijection

Tags: modular-arithmetic, cryptography

I need help with proving that function $E: \mathbb{Z_n} \to \mathbb{Z_n}, \ E(s) = s^e (\mbox{mod n}), \ \ gcd(e, \phi(n))=1$ is bijection.

I need to show that:

a) $E(x) = E(y) \Rightarrow x = y $

b) $ \forall y \in \mathbb{Z_n} \ \ \ \exists x \in \mathbb{Z_n} \ \ \ E(x) = y $

So in a) I have $E(x) = E(y) \Rightarrow x^e = y^e (\mbox{mod n}) \ \ \Rightarrow x^e - y^e = 0 (\mbox{mod n})$. What now?

Comment: Since $\gcd(e,\phi(n))=1$, there exists $d$ such that $ed\equiv1\bmod \phi(n)$; the map $x\mapsto x^d$ is then an inverse of the map $x\mapsto x^e$

Comment: this might not apply unless $\gcd(s,n)=1$ though; for example, if $e=5$ and $n=27$, then $E(3)=E(6)=E(9)$

Answer (score 1):

Take $n=12$, $\phi(n)=4, e=3$, $6^3=0$ mod $12$